# chinese character recognition using Tesseract OCR

Tags: iphone, ios, ocr, tesseract

I have been using Tesseract 3.0.2 OCR SDK for image text extraction. But if I use Chinese text images and pass through OCR then Tesseract doesn't provide me the Chinese characters instead of that I am getting numeric and english characters. But I need Chinese characters as displayed in the image I am using.

How can I achieve this? Is there any way I can obtain Chinese characters rather than any other characters?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to download chinese trained data (it will be a file like **chi_sim.traineddata**) and add it to your **tessdata** folder.

To download the file
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/chi_sim.traineddata

and use like this

```
Tesseract* tesseract= [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"tessdata" language:@"chi_sim"];
```

if you have any problem you can download my experiment with tessaract (with chinese language support) from 
https://github.com/aryansbtloe/ExperimentWithTesseract.git

I have tested this one...Hope you will find this useful.

Comment: Alok, I tried your sample and it works well on about half of simplified Chinese characters I tried. For the rest it may either recognize a compound character as several different characters each representing a component in the compound character, or totally wrong. Do you know of any method to improve the accuracy of recognition?

Comment: New trained data link is https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/chi_sim.traineddata

Comment: download installer from github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki, so to have a tessdata folder. (in addition to pip install pytesseract)