# How to set parameters in tesseract in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, swift, tesseract

I want to set control parameters in tesseract for chinese language in "Objective C" for my iOS project. Can anybody help me?

Comment: this [link][1] is used for chinese character recognition using Tesseract OCR

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581626/chinese-character-recognition-using-tesseract-ocr

Comment: http://maniacdev.com/2014/01/open-source-template-and-example-projects-for-the-tesseract-ocr-library-on-ios-7-with-xcode-5

Comment: I am asking about control parameters. https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=870

Answer (score 0):

Using [this version of Tesseract compiled for iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS):

```
Tesseract *tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"chi_sim"]; //simplified chinese
```

Additional documentation can be found in the readme of the github project linked above.